# How to open/run a vscode (Visual Studio Code) project in the terminal

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

I am creating a TTS (Text To Speech) porgram and one possibility I found involved running the program through through the terminal (example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LRUZ668ZSVU). The example is for python specifically, and so I looked to find what to put for vscode i found this: `vscode://file/FULL/PATH/TO/FILE` and this:`code .` both of which give me an error message saying "no such file or directory." Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong or an easier way to do it?

Comment: What happens if you simply run `code` with no path argument? And what OS is this on?

Comment: when I run just code I get this: `No command 'code' found, did you mean:
 Command 'cdde' from package 'cdde' (universe)
 Command 'tcode' from package 'emboss' (universe)
 Command 'cobe' from package 'python-cobe' (universe)
 Command 'cde' from package 'cde' (universe)
 Command 'ode' from package 'plotutils' (universe)
 Command 'node' from package 'nodejs-legacy' (universe)
code: command not found`
My os is Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia

Comment: This means you don't have VS Code on `PATH`. I don't know how Linux Mint installs things, but you might need to find where VS Code was installed and manually add the location of `code` to your `PATH`.